# manually install devexpress VCL v2011 vol 1.8 components

Tags: delphi, installation, devexpress, delphi-xe

what would be the right sequence (to avoid dependency errors) when manually installing the components under Delphi XE2 (under windows 7 x64) ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use their installer?

Comment: He askes a valid question in respect of Teechart. Dev Express installs a print system (if you've paid for it!) which looks for TeeChart. A basic Teechart is deployed with Delphi but is often replaced again by Steema's own Teechart (recommended!), thus leaving Dev Express installation until last after you have sorted out TeeChart is usually a good idea. That said, I've had few problems simply running their installer.

Comment: Would the Dec 26 VCL 2.3 release from Dev Express help? I haven't used Teechart so I don't the specifics to the issue at hand, or to whether this hotfix item fixes the problem: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S38583.aspx. The 2.3 What's New document says "Delphi XE2 (64-bit) - Add support for TeeChart Pro 2011"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved .... it seems the compiler (DCC32.EXE) was wrong size so the installer kept misfiring.